# TFS Release Management has a release stuck In Progress

Tags: tfs, release-management

Our Release Managemeng has a job that is stuck "In Progress".

The error is

> Communication with the deployer was lost during the deployment. Please
>   make sure (1) the deployer machine has not rebooted during
>   installation and (2) the component timeout is sufficient to copy the
>   files from the drop location to the deployer machine and install the
>   package.

I can't stop or abandon the release.  The buttons are all disabled.  How can I kill this?

Comment: Is this hosted TFS (visual studio online) or a local TFS server?

Comment: -1 wt? Why do people do that without a reason?

Comment: I came in yesterday...and it seems to have unstuck itself

Comment: I had a similer issue, my release was showing"Pending" status indefinitely.

In my case: My RM license was expired and it was not showing any warning message on that. But when i restarted "Release Management Monitor" service, it was showing license expired..!!!

Answer (score 2):

From the Release Manager, go to the Release tab. Enter in the details of the actual release, go to the step that is pending and you will see a a "Stop" Button at the top. That will stop the step and change the step of the Release.

Comment: As mentioned, the buttons were all disabled, so I couldn't click stop

Comment: Stopping wasn't enough . I had to go back and click on abandon the build. I also had to go to c:\windows\dtdownloads folder and remove the content

Answer (score 1):

Is the build stuck? Can you restart the build controller and / or the build agent? You can look for them by editing the build definition.

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust me as Release Management is pretty new, but the error is about the connection between the RM Server and the RM Deployer service (i.e. the RM agent). RM Server don't know anything more about the agent, so your option is to connect to the target machine(s) and manually check deployment status. If completed, restart the RM Deployer service and cross fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue of the release being stuck in 'In Progress' state. Turned out, the password of the credentials I was using, changed. Once the new password was specified in the deployment agent, the release managed to complete. This was months ago, and now I am facing same issue on other server. No clue what is the reason this time.

Comment: Restart "Release Management Monitor" service and see.

Answer (score 0):

We has had this problem in which all releases got stuck on TFS 2018

As there  is a connectivity issue with SQL when release is completed , it may not update the status in DB in some cases if load is more, so the release is stuck in InProgress state and started consuming pipeline in SQL . Other releases will also not move ahead, as there is blockage in pipeline. Once we increase the pipeline count, the problematic release could move out as processing of releases started happening.

Once the problematic release is canceled by the system, we set the pipeline back to original count of 1, then you could see their releases progressing and not being stuck.

Solution:

You need to increase the count of pipeline to let say 25 after this create a new Release Pipeline and queue this pipeline this will push all those pipeline which got stuck .Once pipeline start queuing make the count back to one or original count.

[image]

Reference - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/11/14/understanding-build-and-release-pipelines-visual-studio-team-servicesteam-foundation-server/